# iOS 7 hover/click issue - no click triggered in some cases

Tags: ios, css, hover, click, mobile-safari

I have a kind of "widget" - a data table with some rich functionality like sorting, row selection and else.

In some cases (widget placement/nesting in DOM) clicks on it's rows are not triggered in iOS 7 Safari.

Widget is using jQuery 1.6.4

I can't publish a whole widget code (and you really wan't this to happen ;)), but I can narrow down a reproduction scenario to the following case:

1. Simple html table with some rows, two cols in each
2. First column contains a "checkbox" - simple `div` which is normally hidden and becomes visible, then parent row getting hovered. Visibility is triggered with CSS only
3. Every row has a `click` event handler. No mater what it does. In my example it will trigger an `alert()`
4. Table's parent is a block element with a fixed height and `overflow-y` set to `auto`
5. Table is bigger than it's parent, so, some table content is hidden and can be seen with scrolling

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/822eG/4/

On any desktop browser items are successfully hovered, click is triggered. On iOS7 hover is working but click is NOT triggered.

**NOTE**: On iOS you must tap twice to trigger `click`. First click will trigger `hover` and you'll see a "checkbox", then second tap must trigger a `click`, but it doesn't...

Any of those conditions is REQUIRED to reproduce an issue. Remove a single one and it starts working...

If you remove a "checkbox" appearance - click will work (http://jsfiddle.net/822eG/5/).

If you remove a height fix - it will work (http://jsfiddle.net/822eG/6/).

If you remove a overflow scrolling - it will work (http://jsfiddle.net/822eG/8/).

Any workaround is needed but functionality should be kept untouched. So, I can't remove "checkbox", size fix, hovering, clicking or overflow scrolling. Also, changing HTML markup is hardly to happen.

**NOTE** I've got a solution - see my answer below. But I still need a better workaround to keep using CSS as mush as possible.

**ADD**: Filed a bug to Apple #16072132

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
.wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get iOS to ignore hover states, try this:

```
.wrapper 
{cursor: pointer;}
```

You can use this on any element to get it to function as expected.

Comment: This isn't controlling anything beyond defining what the cursor should look like when hovering over `.wrapper`.

Comment: @JakeWilson Have you tried it? I've had this issue many times and it still fixes it today.

Answer (score 2):

Suddenly, I've got a solution... Using JavaScript I can remove `:hover` selector but still keep functionality.

If I will trigger checkbox visibility not by CSS `:hover` but by class and set it via javascript, it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/822eG/10/

Answer (score 1):

My current working solution requires no any changes in a whole code base and works fine in our conditions

1. With `MutationObserver`, monitor node insertion into `head`
2. If new node is inserted, and this is a `link`, check `document.styleSheets`
3. For each sheet check it's rules
4. If rule selector (access by `document.styleSheets[n].rules[i].selectorText`) contains `:hover` check styles for this selector
5. If styles contains `display` different from `none` or `visibility` different from `visible` - this is a "show by hover" style
6. For each such style change it's selector - replace `:hover` by `.hover` and declare a `body` delegate for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events which will toggle `.hover` class on triggered element

Full source code here: https://gist.github.com/Olegas/9143277

Comment: Your 'full source' link cuts out at line 97 in the middle of a function. It looks like this isn't true in your previous revisions.

Answer (score -2):

..try using this:

```
$('.row').on('touchstart click', function(){
      alert('clicked'); 
});
```

Comment: But... If I begin to scroll... I'll get `touchstart`, isn't it?